# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I get the following error.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid SQL statement or JDBC escape, terminating ''' not found.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:1155)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLParser.parse(SQLParser.java:156)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeImpl(JtdsStatement.java:684)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.execute(JtdsStatement.java:1160)
```

and my code is as follow:

```
context.Createtbl = null;    
String header = ((String)globalMap.get("row1.HeaderString"));    
context.Createtbl="CREATE TABLE ["+context.tblnamewithindex+"] (["+header+"] VARCHAR(max));";
System.out.println(context.Createtbl);
```

what is the exact problem in my code ?

Comment: So what is the output shown on the console?

Comment: `System.out.println(context.Createtbl);` - whats getting printed here?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [Yamaha_2DF] ([PK |||||||||||||||||||| [content_types].xml

Comment: lot of junk characters.

Comment: are you trying to create table? if so, this is not valid syntax in SQL Server to create the table as far as i know.

Comment: I am creating a table by fetching the first row from the excel sheet. and my table name contains the file name.

Comment: If your table name can contain the `]` character you need to use [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) on the header instead of adding the rectangular brackets yourself. QUOTENAME will properly escape the header name.